# ParseException: Unparseable date: "Tue, 31 Mar 2015 06:53:00 +0200" (at offset 0)

Tags: android, parsing, rss

I know this problem was discussed before but i don't find until now a valid answer for my problem.
I parse with XMLPullParser a RSS to get some sport news:
http://www.tennisleader.fr/fil-d-infos/rss

When i format the String object to Date, i keep getting this Exception.

If i replace in formatter with a simple string like : "Tue, 31 Mar 2015 11:35:47 +0000" the formatter it's working.
It's like i have wrong characters in the string object.

And for some of the String pubDate strings also work, and i carefully watch if somehow the format is different for the same RSS source.

I set the formatter to this pattern:

```
formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz", Locale.ENGLISH); //Tue, 31 Mar 2015 10:56:34 +0000  Mon, 30 Mar 2015 23:52:00 +0200
```

LogCat:

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Tue, 31  Mar 2015 06:12:00 +0200" (at offset 0)
```

Format sequence:

```
                Date date1 = null;
                Date date2 = null;

                try {

                    String date1String = item.pubDate;
                    String date2String = item2.pubDate;

                    date1 = formatter.parse(date1String);
                    date2 = formatter.parse(date2String);

                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
String content=DateFormatter.format(parser.getText());
```

parser is the the XmlPullParser object.

It works fine on my application.

Answer (score 0):

This code works!

```
//pubDate = Mon, 16 May 2016 15:09:00 +0200    

String strCurrentDate = getNode("pubDate", eElement);

SimpleDateFormat date_format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE', 'dd' 'MMM' 'yyyy' 'HH:mm:ss' 'Z", Locale.US);

Date pubdate = date_format.parse(strCurrentDate);
```

Look at this: https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html